# how to get all row count of a table from rowcount after having top row filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sqlperformance

I have a huge table in my database and a stored procedure accessing it, which needs pagination.

To achieve this I want total records of the table, and for that, I am facing performance issue because for doing that I need to run this query twice:

- First time to get count for all records
- Secondly when I need to select records in that page range

Is there any way I can avoid the first query for getting the total count instead of I can use row count or something else?

Comment: It would help if you share your query and your requirements, ideally a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can do something like `row_number() over(...) / @rows_per_page as page_num` and then use `page_num` in where clause. But two queries solution _should_ be faster in most cases.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), in this method, you scroll by jumping to a certain key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (your list of columns),
    COUNT(*) OVER ()       
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY
    (whatever column you want to order by)
    OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY;
```

With the `OFFSET / FETCH`, you retrieve only a page of data - and the `COUNT(*) OVER()` will give you the total count of the rows in the table - all in a single query